# Fitting an ARMA model and simulate new time series in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to fit an ARMA model on a given time series 'resid' of length 'tsteps' and use the obtained fitted model 'resid_model' to simulate a certain number of alternative time series with the same characteristics.

Here is what I have tried so far (for only one simulation 'sim'):

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt

resid_model = smt.ARMA(resid, (2, 1)).fit(maxlag=30, ic='aic', trend='nc',disp=False, transparams=True)
sim = smt.arma_generate_sample(ar=np.append(1.,resid_model.arparams), 
               ma=np.append(1.,resid_model.maparams), nsample=tsteps, sigma=resid_model.sigma2)
```

However, I don't seem to be able to ensure stationarity, despite the 'transparams=True' parameter in the fit.
What I obtain depends on the order of the ARMA model I try to fit, but in general tends to degenerate:
[obtained simulation 'sim'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivNxr.png)

This is how my original sample looks like instead:
[original time series 'resid'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22Z9.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with non-stationarity is, but the ar lag polynomial needs to use negtive ar params, `ar=np.append(1., -resid_model.arparams)` (We take it to the left side in the ARMA process equation.)

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem was just that!